# expose age range in views but DOB field is date

Tags: views, datetime

I want to expose an age range in a view (select registered users of age between 25-50) . I tried birthday module and also tried adding a Date of Birth field to user profile using Profile2 Module .

And I think [Views Contextual Range Filter](https://drupal.org/project/contextual_range_filter) works with ranges (25--100) not with dates .

any ideas ? 
thanks

Comment: Solved : used computed field , as described in the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module (in beta in 7). You would simply add a new field, of say age, and of Computed type, (follow a walkthrough [here](http://www.kadimi.com/en/age-from-date-of-birth-in-drupal-7)) and then use a Filter in the View to select the range of ages that you require.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad I could help